# Error suma number en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo una variable de tipo number que al sumarle una cantidad, en vez de ser sumada se añade a continuación.

Aquí dejo el código de creación de la interfaz:

```
interface IPersonaje {
    nombre: string;
    img: string;
    oro: number;
    energia: number;
    poder: number;
    ultcon: string;
}
```

Los valores los añado recogiendo los datos de la base de datos, oro es de tipo int.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
this.user.oro += recompensa;
```

Supongamos que `this.user.oro` tiene valor de 100 e intento sumarle otra variable por valor de 50, pues el resultado es 10050.
En cambio si a esta misma cantidad se la resto, el valor es de 50.

Ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
console.log('oro mas 50',this.user.oro + 50 )
console.log('oro menos 50',this.user.oro - 50)
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente
[image: oro mas 50 10050; oro menos 50 50]

Tambien ejecuta bien las multiplicaciones y las divisiones, en el único que ocurre el problema es en la suma.
Si trato de hacer un parseInt, me salta el siguiente error, dado que ya es un number

> No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "number" al parámetro de tipo "string".

Si ejecuto un `console.log(typeof this.user.oro);` me devuelve string, pese haberlo creado number y no me deja ejecutar ni `parseInt()`, ni `parseFloat()`, ni `Number.parseInt()`

Comment: ¿Usas Typescript o Javascript?

Comment: El proyecto está en angular, asi que Typescript

Comment: A pesar que tu variable TypeScript está definida como number, el valor en tiempo de ejecución es de tipo `string`. El problema ocurre al obtenerlo desde la base de datos, desde un api o al parsear un json. Verifica que los tipos de datos son correctos en todas las capas de tu aplicación.

Comment: ¿Y dónde o cómo inicializas ese `user`? Ya me imagino que lo sacas de la base de datos, pero enséñanos esa parte del código.

Comment: Javascript y Typescript siempre an tenido ese problema en hacer sumas, lo que puedes hacer es usar la librería de numeral ella te permite hacer las operaciones matemáticas básicas, si en this.user.oro es un string, numeral te va a permitir obtener ese valor listo para hacer una operación matemática de esta manera numeral(this.user.oro), agregado a esto le puedes agregar el. add() que te permitirá hacer una suma ejemplo: numeral(this.user.oro).add(recompensa).value() así pudieras hacer una suma con string fácil sin preocuparte, para más te puedes ver la doc de numeral http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: pregunta del 2020 que nunca se dio por solucionada y la respondieron 2 años después...

Answer (score 0):

`this.user.oro` esta definido como `string` o recibe un dato tipo `string`. Para que funcione tu suma puedes usar [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/parseFloat)

```
this.user.oro = '1'

    console.log(this.user.oro + 50)
    console.log(parseFloat(this.user.oro) + 50)
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo que simula ese problema](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ynky8o).

Comment: Hola buenas, al hacer el parseFloat me contesta con el mismo error que con el parseInt: No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "number" al parámetro de tipo "string".

Comment: Lo hiciste con `recompensa` tambien?

Answer (score 0):

Debes declarar la variable `oro` de tu `user` como `number`.

Te recomiendo que también hagas un tipo para los objetos del mismo que `user`, si no lo tienes.

```
interface User {
    // ...
    oro: number;
}
```

A la hora de crear un `User`, a su propiedad `oro` no se le podrán asignar valores que no sean numéricos.

```
const user: User = {
    // ...
    oro: 5
};

const sum = user.oro + 10;
console.log(sum);           // 15
console.log(typeof sum);    // number
```

El símbolo `+` en Javascript sirve la operación suma entre numéricos como para la concatenación de *strings*.

```
const x = 4 + 5; // 9
const y = '4' + 5; // 45
```

Comment: Hola buenas,al crear el usuario, ya tenia declarado que era number:
 interface IPersonaje {
    nombre:string;
    img:string;
    oro:number;
    energia:number;
    poder:number;
    ultcon:string;
}
Si que es verdad que cuando hago el typeof me devuelve que es string, pero aun así no me deja efectuar el parseInt

Comment: Deberías añadir a la pregunta cómo está definida esta interfaz `IPersonaje` y cómo inicializas ese objeto `user`.

Comment: ya está actualizada :)

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he conseguido arreglarlo creando una segunda variable y haciendo lo siguiente:

```
var oro = parseInt(this.user.oro.toString());
console.log('oro + 2 = ',oro + 2) //así ya realiza la suma
```

No tiene mucho sentido el código pero funciona.

Comment: No es un comportamiento normal. Deberias analizar cuando asignas oro si algo esta pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Por algún motivo la propiedad `oro` te llega de la base de datos convertido en un string, con lo que no cumple la interfaz:

```js
interface IPersonaje {
    nombre: string;
    img: string;
    oro: number;
    energia: number;
    poder: number;
    ultcon: string;
}

const aux = {
    nombre: 'Frodo',
    img: '',
    oro: '100', //ponemos un string
    energia: 100,
    poder: 5,
    ultcon: '?'
}

const personaje: IPersonaje = aux as unknown as IPersonaje; //forzamos el tipado
//console.log(parseInt(personaje.oro)); //error de compilación : Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
console.log(personaje.oro + 5); //muestra "1005"
```

Puesto que los tipos de typescript sólo son orientaciones para el programador, no hay manera de que el compilador te avise de que esto está mal.

##### Solución "correcta":

Arreglar el API para que realmente cumpla con la interfaz (contrato)

##### Apaño rápido:

Cambiar la interfaz para que typescript no se queje cuando uses `parseInt`, `parseFloat` o `+` para transformar el string a number.